# Ударение при склонении топонима Черлак (посёлок)

Tags: грамотная-речь, топонимика

Сохраняется ли ударение при склонении названия посёлка Черлак Омской области на корневой ***а*** или переходит на последнюю гласную, как при склонении слов "чердак", "кулак", "батрак"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы не рискнула переносить ударение, ориентируясь на "чердак" или "челнок".

Оставила б как есть:

Черл**а**к, Черл**а**ка, Черл**а**ку, Черл**а**к, Черл**а**ком, (о) Черл**а**ке.

Прислушаться можно вот к чему:

[Ударение в географических названиях](http://gramota.ru/slovari/info/ag/pravila/)

> При выборе вариантов ударения отечественных географических названий
>   ***обращается внимание на местное ударение***. Отделы дикторов Всесоюзного радио и Центрального телевидения периодически посылали
>   запросы в местные комитеты по телевидению и радиовещанию, в
>   постпредства республик, специальным корреспондентам телевидения и
>   радио в разных городах по поводу ударения в тех или иных
>   географических названиях...
>
> Но в подходе к норме ударения отечественных и заимствованных топонимов
>   учтено существование двух противоположных тенденций: 1) стремление
>   приблизиться к местному произношению и 2) стремление сохранять
>   традиционное ударение, свойственное русскому языку. Безоговорочное
>   следование той или другой тенденции неправильно, требуется подход
>   конкретно к каждому случаю. **Если ударение в местном названии
>   расходится с общепринятым в русском литературном языке, не
>   соответствует акцентной системе русского языка, то принимается
>   традиционный вариант, характерный для литературного  языка**...

Подробнее - по ссылке.

Не трогайте ударение именительного падежа.

---

Нашла **[рассказ ДИКТОРА](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HwtuKq6FvfY)**! Я ПРАВА!

Comment: Галин, меня одно смущает: *на букве а - Черлака - или переходит...* Можно подумать, что рассматривается только родительный падеж. Написал сюда, а не под вопросом, чтобы не прописывать всех собачек.

Comment: Тёмыч, не помню, сам автор или я влезла, выделив шрифтом. Автор спрашивает о перемещении ударения с корневого ***а*** на конечное в родительном падеже. Можно отдельно спросить и о дательном, но я там все жалких шесть (минуя второй родительный, второй предложный и один звательный)  нарисовала. Как оне мне видятся.

Comment: Мне тоже подумалось было, что он спрашивает о родительном, но на самом деле он спрашивает о всех. Он спрашивает, сохраняется ли на А ударение, вот я и думаю, что в родительном две А, и в итоге понимаю, что он спрашивал вообще о разных падежах.

Comment: Ты мою ссылочку дописанную посмотри, или Вот как находятся ответы на проклятые вопросы.

Comment: Вот это круто! Но дать три голоса за ответ не могу, к сожалению.)))

Comment: Тёмыч, спасибо за светлый порыв! А крутее буде, если спасёшь сминусованное (обидно ж): https://rus.stackexchange.com/users/177616/galina-avanesova?tab=answers&sort=votes&page=22

Comment: @GalinaAvanesova Согласна с Артёмом — нет возможности дополнительно снять шляпу.

Comment: Римулька Лорхенова, Вы а) пачиму мой коммент игнорнули, где я дала свой адрес для связи? linaglat@mail.ru ; б) помогите в борьбе с бото-бегемотами: https://rus.stackexchange.com/users/177616/galina-avanesova?tab=answers&sort=votes&page=22